# How to get particular value from JSON response in Android?

Tags: android, android-json

I want to get the value of `"result"` from the below JSON response and store it locally.Here's the code:

```
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        //JSONArray contacts;
                        contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response");
                        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + contacts);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
                return null;
        }
    }
```

My Response :

```
{"response":

        [{
            "name":"ajay",
            "class":"7",
        },

        {
            "rank":1
        }],


        "date":

        {
            "startdate":2/12/2012,
        },
            "result":"pass"
        }
```

Comment: You have to understand that SO is not there to do your work for you, we're here to solve technical questions.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM..I am a new for this kind of development.

Comment: There's a difference between asking how to parse a JSON and asking for the whole code to solve a given problem. You are paid money to do that, so don't delegate your job onto someone else.

Comment: To parse a JSON, I recommend you look into GSON, a google library.

Comment: To store it in a file, the File java library does the trick just right.

Comment: Piling on with the other comments, but this question is not specific and well-defined enough to get a good answer. Please see the [ask] page for more details on asking a good question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a JSON Object from json String, you get and then retrieve its data:

```
JSONObject json= new JSONObject(responseString);  //your response
try {
    String result = json.getString("result");    //result is key for which you need to retrieve data
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what happens? Not getting result or exception? @Mano

Comment: Sorry @MysticMagic...I made some mistakes...Your Answer working good Thank you so much...Sorry Again..

Comment: @Mano that's ok :) glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Please provide correct and full JSON response. So I can show you the way to parse the JSON :

```
String jsonStr;  // hold your JSON response in String
try {
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    // If you have array
    JSONArray resultArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("response"); // Here you will get the Array

    // Iterate the loop
    for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length(); i++) {
        // get value with the NODE key
        JSONObject obj = resultArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String name =  obj.getString("name");
    }

    // If you have object
    String result = json.getString("result");

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: `result` is a String. check response in question.

Comment: downvote ? rather i believe in correcting the answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this...

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    // Creating service handler class instance
    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

     if (jsonStr != null) {
      try {
      JSONObject json= new JSONObject(jsonStr);  //your json response
      String result = json.getString("result");    //result data
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
     }
    }
```